# Security error accessing url Unable to load WSDL

Tags: flash, web-services, flex4

we have an internal webservice developed in our company and i have connected that web service using flex and am able to get all the methods/operations from that service. but wen i try to get data from methods i get the following error msg while running the application

Security error accessing url
Unable to load WSDL. If currently online, please verify the URI and/or format of the WSDL (http://ispl30:8080/MGEMWS/MGEMWS?wsdl)

am not able to figure out what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the WSDL is available in a web browser from the computer you're running the flex SWF (without flex proxy) or from the server (using flex proxy).

If you're not using flex proxy, are you hosting the flex SWF and the webservice on the same host ? 
Consider usage of cross domain policy:

See http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html

Comment: Hi, webservice is in other host. if i run through only flex then it will work fine. but if i run through tomcat then it gives that security error.